# PyQGIS script no longer works without giving errors

Tags: pyqgis, raster-calculator

I am new to using PyQGIS.

I wrote the following script that initially worked, now instead it runs gdal_translate and then stops, doesn't run the raster calculator, without returning any errors.

If I change the output format of the raster calculator from .jp2 to .tif then it executes it.

Anyone have any idea why?

I'm using QGIS 3.16

```
import gdal
import gdalconst
import processing

#Inputs
S2_B2_10m = "D:\...\T32TLR_20201031T103201_B02_10m.jp2"
S2_B3_10m = "D:\...\T32TLR_20201031T103201_B03_10m.jp2"
S2_B5_20m = "D:\...\T32TLR_20201031T103201_B05_20m.jp2"

#Intermediary outputs
S2_B2_20m = "D:\...\T32TLR_20201031T103201_B02_20m.jp2"
S2_B3_20m = "D:\...\T32TLR_20201031T103201_B03_20m.jp2"

#Pre-processing
gdal.Translate(S2_B2_20m, S2_B2_10m, xRes=20, yRes=20, resampleAlg=gdalconst.GRA_Cubic)
gdal.Translate(S2_B3_20m, S2_B3_10m, xRes=20, yRes=20, resampleAlg=gdalconst.GRA_Cubic)

#Snow detection
NDSI = "D:\...\T32TLR_20201031T103201_NDSI.jp2"
parameters = {'INPUT_A' : S2_B2_20m,
        'INPUT_B' : S2_B5_20m,
        'BAND_A' : 1,
        'BAND_B' : 1,
        'FORMULA' : '((A-B)/(A+B))',
        'OUTPUT' : NDSI}

processing.runAndLoadResults('gdal:rastercalculator', parameters)
```

Comment: Try adding [r](https://www.askpython.com/python/string/python-raw-strings) in front of all paths, for example `S2_B2_10m = r"D:\...\T32TLR_20201031T103201_B02_10m.jp2"`

Comment: No errors in any of the message panels?

Comment: @bugmenot123 no any error

Comment: have you tried using `gdal.UseExceptions()` after your import statements ?